# 15.10 - Unity-Mail not in Repository anymore?

Tags: unity, software-installation, repository, mail

I just installed Ubuntu 15.10 clean on my machine. When I want to install Unity-Mail  via apt-get or Software-Center I get the message, that the package cannot be found.

But it seems that the Package is still avaidable here https://launchpad.net/unity-mail

Answer (score 3):

Sadly Unity-Mail is no longer developed for [the following reasons](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-mail/+bug/1465703):

> - Dead upstream (I no longer have time to develop it).
> - Thunderbird has good Unity integration nowadays (unity-mail was written when it was not the case).
> - unity-mail is incompatible with Unity 8.
> - No reverse depends.

As long as we are not using Unity8 we can still install it from ppa:

```
ppa:robert-tari/main
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is looking for an alternative, there is a program called `mailnag` that basically serves the same purpose:

https://github.com/pulb/mailnag

http://www.webupd8.org/2016/03/mailnag-email-notifier-12-released-with.html

I've installed it on Ubuntu 15.10 and it's working great. (Make sure to install `mailnag-unity-plugin` as well though)